# A method to create and assign a name to a GameObject (Unity)

Tags: c#, game-loop, unity

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a name of an object in the editor and assigns this accordingly as well as the name of a sprite, rigidbody, etc.

Basically what I have so far is-

```
    public void thing_maker(string gameobject_name, string sprite_name, string rg_body_name)
```

which is apparently impossible to implement...

Basically my question is how can I convert a string to a GameObject name (I guess)?

EDIT:

Or, rather, is there any actually (developmentally) time saving way to use a method to create a gameobject with a specific name, then assign components with respective, specific names?

Comment: Are you talking about components instead of gameobjects? Gameobject.Addcomponent is your friend.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. What o you mean by *giving things names*? Do you mean assigning its name property to a value? Do you mean dynamically generating a class with a specific name? Aaaaaaa. :) Short description of *what exactly you expect to see* would help.

Comment: I'm seeing a bit of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.  I figured since the question was automatically nudged to the top again and there hadn't been any clarification, I thought I'd ask.  @novasniff : what is it that you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to name the Sprite Renderer or Rigid body component. You can set the GameObject's name, which appears in the editor's hierarchy, by setting the gameobject.name to your desired value.

So my advice would be to do something like this:

```
public static class ObjectCreator
{
    public static GameObject NewObject(GameObject prefab, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, string name)
    {
        GameObject newObj = Object.Instantiate (prefab, position, rotation) as GameObject;
        newObj.name = name;
        return newObj;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I just reread your question and considered that you might be talking about object creation before runtime (i.e. editor scripting), in which case I'm not in a position to advise since I've never delved into that myself

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is, you want to create a `GameObject` with a specific sprite image, and `Rigidbody`.

This is called Instantiating a prefab. The steps are as follows:

1. Drag and drop your sprite into the hierarchy. Name it whatever you wish.
2. Add a `Rigidbody2D` component to it.
3. Drag and drop that object into your assets.
4. Now you have a prefab. This prefab can be instantiated in many ways. Irrespective of which method you use to instantiate it, what happens is, you create an object that is exactly like the prefab you just created. Complete with attached scripts (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You can't name components in Unity; they are named with their Type automatically. But you can name a GameObject with following code piece:

```
GameObject.name = "Name";
```

---

**Edit:** I just realised you are talking about storing components. Well, this is an "expensive" way, but here you go:

```
public Rigidbody rb;

void Start () 
{
    rb.angularDrag = ...;
    rb.centerOfMass = ...;
    rb.collisionDetectionMode = ...;
    rb.drag = ...;
    .
    .
    .
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    Rigidbody added = GameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>() as Rigidbody;

    added.angularDrag = rb.angularDrag;
    added.centerOfMass = rb.centerOfMass;
    added.drag = rb.drag;
    .
    .
    .
}
```